# Type 'false' is not assignable to type 'EventEmitter<any>'

Tags: angular, typescript

I have to pass a boolean value to the Parent Component but while doing so I am getting an error stating that " Type 'false' is not assignable to type 'EventEmitter'. "

Here is the code for it,

```
 @Output() isTimeBoundAccessEnabled = new EventEmitter();
```

and here is how I am assigning a boolean Value as FALSE when a certain condition fails

```
 this.isTimeBoundAccessEnabled = false ;
```

What is exactly the mistake in my code?

Comment: Looks like the type of `isTimeBoundAccessEnabled` is being inferred by the assignment. If you want to assign false to `isTimeBoundAccessEnabled` give it of type `EventEmitter | false`

Answer (score 2):

The right way is:

```
@Output() isTimeBoundAccessEnabled = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

this.isTimeBoundAccessEnabled.emit(false);
```

Answer (score 2):

To pass `false` to the parent (from the child component) you should `emit` values like:

```js
// in child component
this.someEventEmitter.emit(false);
```

Then the parent has an event handler for that like

```html
<MyChild (customEvent)="handleEvent($event)"> ...
```

and in parent class we have `handleEvent`

```js
handleEvent($event){
  console.log($event); // should be `false` if child executed the above code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are not Emitting the value and assigning it. Make sure to emit the values while using the emitter. In your case you can use what other in the above answers have mentioned. Also make sure to use correct type of EventEmitter.

```
this.isTimeBoundAccessEnabled.emit(false);
```